# how to implement compostion in c#

Tags: c#

I have two classes A and B in which two properties 'prop1' and 'prop2' are common. How can I have compostion implemented. May be Class C can have these common properties. Its a has-a relationship and not is-a.

```
public class A {
 public int Prop1{get;set;}
 public int Prop2 {get; set;}
 public int Prop3{get;set;}
 public int Prop4 {get; set;}

}

public class B {
 public int Prop1{get;set;}
 public int Prop2 {get; set;}
 public int Prop5{get;set;}
 public int Prop6 {get; set;}
}
```

If I have a interface say C and have these two common properties in it would that classify as composition? Something like

```
inferace C {
 int Prop1{get;set;}
 int Prop2 {get; set;}
}

public class A : C
{

}

public class B : C
{
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: No, that's not composition. Composition would be a class C containing variables of types A and B.

Comment: Thanks. So how can do that? Please can you give me an example?

Comment: You should try things for yourself first. I've suggested a class with variables of types A and B - have you tried that? What went wrong wrong you did so? What are you actually trying to achieve? Have you read http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object_composition for more details of composition in general?

Comment: basically I have class C with two common properties which are in class A and B as well..So how can I have class c in class A and B. Do I have to create object of class C in both ClassA and B?

Comment: You've asked about composition, but then your question about common properties has nothing to do with composition. What are you actually interested in? If you're just interested in abstracting out the two properties, then the code in your question is fine - but it's not composition.

Comment: I have these two classes A and B. I saw some common properties in both of them and then I decided to have class C with common properties and then Inherited this class with A and B. But then I was reading about inheritance and found that its only for is-a and not has-a relationship. has-a should be compostion.

Comment: Well you *could* create a class with those two properties, and make that a member of each of class A and B, but we can't really tell from this artificial example whether that would be a good thing or not. We can't tell what problem you're trying to solve. Please read http://tinyurl.com/stack-hints

Comment: classA and B are DTO's.  The two common properties are the composit key. Usually I would just include the common properites in A and B but I was just thinking if this can be written neatly. So I thought of inheritance and then compostion.

Answer (score 0):

Implementing an interface is not composition, although that would be an alternative way to avoid duplicating code.

To do this using composition, you should create a new class with Prop1 and Prop2, and have an instance of this class as a property of ClassA and ClassB.

```
public class CompositeKey 
{
    public int Prop1 { get; set; }
    public int Prop2 { get; set; }
}  

public class A 
{
    public CompositeKey Key { get; set; }
    public int Prop3 { get; set; }
    public int Prop4 { get; set; }
}
...
```

This is a bit more flexible than using an interface because you can assign any subtype of CompositeKey to your property at run time, but the main reason you should do it this way is because class A *has* a composite key, you don't want to use your class *as* a CompositeKey.